# Papers differing primarily by examined dataset, not analysis technique

Tags: research-process, computer-science, data

I am considering a specific topic in research paper within data mining field. I just found that my idea is being implemented and published in arXiv in the last month. So far, the published paper matches the flow that I was planning to follow but the author has considered the study with *Twitter data*. My question is: **If I want to do the same experiments but with a different data set like facebook data set will it be considered a new contribution in that field ?**

Ps: Row data crawled from Twitter API is way different from row data crawled from Facebook API, and the also different in structure and body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the main contributions in your field are "algorithms", however, data sets are just a bunch of inputs for testing those algorithms and assessing their functionality or efficiency. If the outcomes of your new tests with data set A are exactly the same as dataset B's ones, you might not claim it as a new contribution. But if the results acquired from dataset B lead to some different interpretations about your algorithm's computational capabilities or something, you can consider it as a new contribution.

Comment: you mean by algorithms - ''machine learning'' ?

Comment: @Krebto: Yes. I mean algorithms are often contributions of machine learning and most of the CS-based research fields.